# How to configure cabal in Windows 7?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have installed Haskell Platform 2012 in Windows 7. I write in the console `cabal update` and I take a message that there is a new version of cabal. I write `cabal install cabal-install` . After installation finishes it tells me that the cabal has been installed in C:\username\AppData\Roaming\cabal. So when I do `cabal update` again I am taking the same message that I have to install the new version of cabal. I have tried to change the cabal directory from the config file but cabal ignores the config file. Is Haskell working only on Unix? Thanks

Comment: IMHO one should never ever use 'cabal install cabal-install' if one just has started the journey with haskell with a fresh haskell plattfrom. Just use cabal update  to update the package list. The only people who should update cabal itself will know when to do that, if you don't know it, don't do it

Comment: @Jonke So when do people do it then?

Comment: When you want the newest release of cabal for a new release of ghc and there is no haskell platform. For instance if you get the binary build for ghc 7.8.2 you can get a binary build for cabal 1.18 but no binary build for cabal 1.20, then you do it. (IMHO)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that the `cabal` executable that came with Haskell Platform gets picked up instead of the one that you installed.

You need to [edit the value of the `PATH` environment variable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) and place `%AppData%\cabal\bin` before `%PROGRAMFILES%\Haskell Platform\...\bin` so that it's given higher priority.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `C:\username\AppData\Roaming\cabal` (or whatever directory now has the `cabal` executable -- use e.g. `dir` or your favorite file manager to verify that you have the right place) to your `%PATH%` environment variable and restart your command prompt.

Comment: The HP installer adds `%APPDATA%\cabal\bin` to `%PATH%` by default; the problem is that `%PLATFORM_DIR%\bin` is given higher priority.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is incomplete. Install cabal-install globally as:

```
cabal install cabal-install --global
```

Comment: Thank you, I never knew about --global