# Haskell 2014.2 on Windows 7 64bit, "cabal update" fails and %APPDATA%\cabal\bin is missing

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

I am aware and have tried ALL solutions suggested in :

[How to configure cabal in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461085/how-to-configure-cabal-in-windows-7)
[Error with cabal update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435856/error-with-cabal-update)
[2014 haskell cabal update hangs on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498161/2014-haskell-cabal-update-hangs-on-mac)
[cabal install pcap windows 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648750/cabal-install-pcap-windows-64bit)
[How to configure cabal in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461085/how-to-configure-cabal-in-windows-7)
[Cabal fails updating of cabal-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366775/cabal-fails-updating-of-cabal-install)
[Gtk2hs windows 7 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251902/gtk2hs-windows-7-installation)

No matter what I do, I can't get "cabal update" to work. It hangs in windows cmd and nothing happens.
What I noticed, is that %APPDATA%\cabal\bin doesn't exist! many other solutions refer to it (to add it in PATH variable.).

When I tried a an older version I also get a socket error message. I have it allowed in my firewall.
Any ideas??

Comment: Depending on how recently you tried this, it may have been due to some Hackage downtime. Hackage is up right now, can you try again and see if it works?

Comment: At the very least you should run `cabal update -v3` so it gives you as much information as possible and if that doesn't tell you what the problem is, you should include it in your question. Is this a clean installation of the Haskell Platform? If not, try doing that, to see if it is your machine or cabal which is broken.

Comment: when I tried `cabal update -v3` it gave me `Creating new connection to hackage.haskell.org` and hung up on it again. I tried clean install many times, but it never changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of `cabal-install` now have the `--http-transport` flag which lets users use PowerShell, wget, or curl if the builtin http library runs into issues with firewalls, etc.